# How to disable sunshaft effect on my main camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a main camera in my scene with a Sun Shafts (Script) ImageEffect on it.
(I'm using Medieval Environment asset.)

I'd like to disable this effect programmatically when main camera reaches a specific coordinate.

Here is my C# script's code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

    public class EnableComponents : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private SunShafts mySunShafts; //<<< Error CS0246 displays here (see below)


        void Start ()
        {
            mySunShafts = GetComponent<SunShafts>();
        }


        void Update ()
        {

            foreach(Camera c in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Camera))) 
            {
                if ((c.name == "Main Camera"))
                {
                    if ((c.transform.position.x < -10))
                    {
                        mySunShafts.enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Here is how SunShafts' code starts:

```
    @script ExecuteInEditMode
    @script RequireComponent (Camera)
    @script AddComponentMenu ("Image Effects/Sun Shafts")

    enum SunShaftsResolution {
        Low = 0,
        Normal = 1,
        High = 2,
    }

    enum ShaftsScreenBlendMode {
        Screen = 0,
        Add = 1,    
    }   

    class SunShafts extends PostEffectsBase 
    {       
        public var resolution : SunShaftsResolution = SunShaftsResolution.Normal;
        public var screenBlendMode : ShaftsScreenBlendMode = ShaftsScreenBlendMode.Screen;
...
...
...
```

When I try to debug the code, following errormessage displays:

**"Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SunShafts' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (Assembly-CSharp)"**

Here you can see that SunShaft effect and the above written C# script belongs to the same camera. However (and this is my problem) the two scripts just "cannot see each other".

[image]

So what am I doing wrong? Why my C# script "cannot see" the Sun Shafts script written in JavaScript? How should I change my C# code to be able to disable the SunShafts effect on my camera in runtime?

======================== EDIT #1 ======================

C# script is already in Plugins folder:

[image]

and here is the errormessage:

[image]

===================== EDIT #2 ==============================

Here is the imported Standard Asset:

[image]

Now there's no problem with UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;

[image]

However I'm getting this error message:

[image]

Comment: Did you try the answer at http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/280984/why-cant-i-access-my-c-class-from-javascript.html ? It's an issue about compilation order, you *can* use your JS class within C# code.

Comment: The strange thing is that I've already added my C# script to Plugins folder. (Please see my edited question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing the assembly import, therefore the compiler doesn't find the SunShaft class.

Place

```
using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;
```

below

```
using System;
```

to import the assembly.

Comment: I did what you suggested (keeping in mind the correct order as well). Following error displayed: Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityStandardAssets' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (Assembly-CSharp-firstpass)

Comment: Please see my edited question. You can see the error message and my "using part" there as well. What's wrong with it?

Comment: In your project folder, you should have a "Standard Assets" sub folder. This then should contain a "ImageEffects" folder, containing, among others, the SunShafts.cs file. If you do not have these folders, you need to re-import the Standard Asset "Effects" package.

Include all the *.cs files from the ImageEffects Folder into your VS solution and you should no longer get these errors.

Comment: Getting closer to the solution... Please see my Edited #2 part in my original question. There's no problem with  "using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;"  part any longer however I've got this error message:   "Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CameraPathAnimator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (Assembly-CSharp-firstpass)"    What should I do now? (I've tried to reimport Camera Path Animator Asset)

Comment: Nevermind. Imported Standard Asset as you've described, then moved my C# script to "Assets" root folder (you can see it on the 1st picture of Edit et part #2), then deleted some duplicated folders in my project, restarted Unity and now I can compile py project.